# Non callable variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a password generator with Python. Everything else seems to work correctly, but when I try to save the password in a .txt file, the program crashes, telling me that `ok_to_save` is "non callable". Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

PS: Don't mind option 6 I'm still experimenting with it.

```
import random
import string

print('Hi, would you like me to create a password that no one can guess ?')
confirmation=input()
print('If you want a password with only letters press 1 and then enter, for one with only numbers press 2 and then enter.')  
print('For a password with both press 3 and then enter.')
print('For a password with letters, numbers and symbols press 4 and then enter.')
print('To remember a password you previously saved in this application press 5 and then enter.')
print('To save a password you made yourself press 6 and then enter')
a=input()
b=''
ok_to_save=''

if a=='1':
        b=input = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(12)])
        print(b)
        print('Would you like me to save this password ?')
        ok_to_save=input()

elif a=='2':
        b=input = ''.join([random.choice(string.digits) for n in
        range(12)])
        print(b)
        print('Would you like me to save this password ?')
        ok_to_save=input()

elif a=='3':
        b=input = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in 
        range(12)])
        print(b)
        print('Would you like me to save this password ?')
        ok_to_save=input()

elif a=='4':
        b=input = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!' + '@' + '#' + '$' + '%' + '^' + '&' + '*' + '(' + ')') for n in range(12)])
        print(b)
        print('Would you like me to save this password ?')
        ok_to_save=input()       

elif a=='5':                               
        f=open("database.txt","r")       
        f=open('database.txt','r')
        print(f.read())

elif a=='6':
        print('What is the password ?')
        alt_b=input()

if ok_to_save=='Yes' or ok_to_save=='yes':        
        print('What is this password for ? ')
        c=input()
        f=open('database.csv','w')
        password=''+b+','+c
        f.write(password)
        f.close()
```

Comment: All of those lines starting with `b=input = ...` are overwriting the built-in `input()` function, meaning that you can no longer prompt the user for input.

Comment: As a general advise, try to create a [mcve]. Copy the code and then remove irrelevant parts. Typically (maybe not here) it also involves removing manual input.

Comment: Option 4 *could* use `string.punctuation`.

Comment: In the future, please show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages - don't just try to describe them from memory. I tried to clarify your description (along with fixing the run-on sentences and [removing irrelevant discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721), but it still doesn't accurately explain what went wrong. Copy and paste exception tracebacks, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and format them like code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so from my experimenting, the issue comes in here. When you do

```
b=input= ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in
        range(12)])
```

What this does is it creates a variable named 'input' and stores the result of the join method in the variable input as well as in the varible b. The reason you get an error at the ok to save line is because you're doing

```
ok_to_save = input()
```

The python interpreter sees input and is thinking that you're referring to the variable that you created above and not the function which takes input and therefore says 'str object not callable' because the str object is not a function that you can call.

As a future reference, avoid creating variables with the same name as functions. To solve your issue that you have now, wherever you have

```
b = input = ...
```

remove the input and make it

```
b = ...
```

or just change input to input1 or something else.
This should resolve the problem.

Comment: I suspect that line is meant to be something like: `b=input(''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!' + '@' + '#' + '$' + '%' + '^' + '&' + '*' + '(' + ')') for n in range(12)]))`

Comment: @Chris Might be but I'm not so sure. They seem to know what input returns and the variable b is meant to store the generated password.

Comment: I also suspect this was a typo or a copy and paste error.